# How to start writing unit tests for Python?

Tags: python, testing

I don't do tests, but I'd like to start. I have some questions:

1. Is it ok to use the `unittest` module for that? From what I understand, the `unittest` module will run any method starting with `test`.
2. if I have a separate directory for the tests ( consider a directory named `tests` ), how would I import the code I'm testing? Do I need to use the `imp` module? Here's the directory structure :

   src/

   tests/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fine to use `unittest`. This module will run methods beginning with `test` for classes which inherit from `unittest.TestCase`.

There's no need to use the `imp` module - your test module would just import the code under test as normal. You might need to add the `src` directory to your path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../src') # OnLinux  - use r'..\src' for Windows
```

This code would be in your test module(s) before any import of your modules.

A better approach is to use the OS environment variable `PYTHONPATH`.

(Windows) `SET PYTHONPATH=path\to\module; python test.py`

(Linux) `PYTHONPATH=path/to/module; python test.py`

An alternative to `unittest` is [nose](http://code.google.com/p/python-nose/).

Comment: Don't mess with `sys.path.append()`.  Use PYTHONPATH, it's much, much simpler.

Comment: I think you meant sys.path there.

Comment: How should PYTHONPATH be used?

Comment: actually, nose isn't an alternative to unittest, but rather an enhancement of it/

Answer (score 5):

Another good way to start tests with your Python code is use the [doctest](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html) module, whereby you include tests inside method and class comments. The neat bit is that these serve as code examples, and therefore, partial documentation. Extremely easy to do, too.

Answer (score 2):

I had a bit of problem with the whole seperate directory for tests issue.

The way I solved it was by having a test runner in the source directory with the following code:

```
import sys, os, re, unittest

# Run all tests in t/

def regressionTest():
    path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])) + '/t'
    files = os.listdir(path)
    test = re.compile("^t_.+\.py$", re.IGNORECASE)
    files = filter(test.search, files)
    filenameToModuleName = lambda f: 't.'+os.path.splitext(f)[0]
    moduleNames = map(filenameToModuleName, files)
    modules = map(__import__, moduleNames)
    modules = map(lambda name: sys.modules[name], moduleNames)
    load = unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromModule
    return unittest.TestSuite(map(load, modules))

suite = regressionTest()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Then I had a folder named `t` containing all my tests, named `t_<something>.py`.

If you need help on getting started with unit testing in Python, I can recommend [the official documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html) and [Dive Into Python](http://diveintopython.net/unit_testing/index.html) among other things.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Sebastian P., Mark Pilgrim's *[Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.org/)* has great chapters on [unit testing](http://www.diveintopython.org/unit_testing/index.html) and [test-driven development](http://www.diveintopython.org/unit_testing/stage_1.html) using Python's unittest module. I used these chapters to get started with testing, myself.

I wrote a blog post describing [my approach to importing modules for testing](http://igotgenes.blogspot.com/2008/12/robust-imports-in-python-guaranteed.html). Note that it solves the shortcoming of Vinay Sajip's approach, which will not work if you call the testing module from anywhere but the directory in which it resides. A reader posted a nice solution in the comments of my blog post as well.

S. Lott hints at a method using `PYTHONPATH` in Vinay's post; I hope he will expound on it.